# Use WOTotalSet to populate WORKORDER field

Tags: maximo

*Maximo Asset Management 7.6.1.2:*

There is a Java class called WOTotalSet that is used in WOTRACK —> View Costs to display the costs of a work order.

[psdi.app.workorder.virtual.WOTotalSet](https://bportaluri.com/wp-content/MaximoJavaDocs76/psdi/app/workorder/virtual/WOTotalSet.html)

I want to use WOTotalSet to populate a field (persistent or non-persistent) in the WORKORDER object. The field would store the WO costs, including task costs.

Is there a way to populate a field using WOTotalSet — via an attribute formula or automation script?

*For what it’s worth, there is a non-persistent object called WOTOTAL that uses WOTotalSet as its class. WOTOTAL has a TOTAL field (includes tasks), which is what I need. But unfortunately, the WOTOTAL object doesn’t have a WONUM or WORKORDERID field. So I have no way to join from WORKORDER to WOTOTAL via a relationship.*

Comment: Hi @User1973 - do you have a minimal reproducible example with the code you have tried so far and any errors you’ve encountered? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Being a virtual class, it is meant to be used on non-persistent objects, so a join won't do you any good anyway. Most likely there is some code in Maximo that triggers the creation of that set, populating an MBO in it (WOTotal), adding up the numbers, and sticking them in the fields on the set and/or the MBO. That trigger could just be fetching the set via a (special) relationship, or (more likely) via an action (like a button press).

Comment: You would need to replicate that trigger (probably a bean loading the dialog, which makes it tricky, so you might have to replicate the logic instead) in an automation script so the set and MBO are populated, then just get the MBO out of the set (wototalmbo = wototalset.getMbo(0), likely), get the value of the field you want from that MBO, and then set that value on your field. I do not have access to the code anymore to look up specifics, so this general design is all I can offer.

Comment: In situations such as this it often helps to decompile the Java classes in question and review the code to determine what it does and whether you can follow a similar pattern.  I would use http://java-decompiler.github.io/ and you can find the classes somewhere like "C:\IBM\SMP\maximo\applications\maximo\businessobjects\classes\psdi\app\workorder\virtual" depending on the specifics of your setup.

Comment: Here's an extract of the decompiled class (unfortunately getting code to format properly here in a comment was not straightforward):

https://gist.github.com/maximo-wiki-user/cd87a4f16f8e38215c330c899fdbe1e0

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve what you're looking for here by simply querying the total cost from the non-persistant field directly on the work order mbo then use that value to set the value of your custom field.  I don't think you need to touch WOTotalSet.

For example:

```
woNum = mbo.getString("WONUM")

woEstAtApprLabCost = mbo.getDouble("ESTATAPPRLABCOST")
woEstTotalCost = mbo.getDouble("ESTTOTALCOST")
woEstAtApprTotalCost = mbo.getDouble("estAtApprTotalCost")
woActTotalCost = mbo.getDouble("ACTTOTALCOST")

service.log("woNum: " + woNum)

service.log("woEstAtApprLabCost: " + str(woEstAtApprLabCost))
service.log("woEstTotalCost: " + str(woEstTotalCost))
service.log("woEstAtApprTotalCost: " + str(woEstAtApprTotalCost))
service.log("woActTotalCost: " + str(woActTotalCost))

mbo.setValue("YOURCUSTOMFIELDHERE",woActTotalCost)
```

Comment: Thanks. I don’t think ACTTOTALCOST includes the task costs does it?

Comment: I'm looking in v.7.6.0.0 and from the work order application if you go to View -> Costs then the dialog that is shown has the following line at the top, "The Work Order Totals table shows the labor and **cost information for the current work order and related tasks**. The Work Package Totals table shows the labor and cost information for the entire work order hierarchy, starting from the current work order."

https://imgur.com/a/3QR3W8U

AFAIK, the fields shown in the code above e.g. "ACTTOTALCOST" include the task costs also but you could verify this based on the figures it provides.

Comment: Thanks. It looks to me like ACTTOTALCOST (non-persistent field) is only a total of the costs within the WO itself (`actlabcost` + `actmatcost` + `acttoolcost` + `actservcost`). It doesn't seem to roll up the task cost to the WO. Maybe the View Costs window adds the "total" costs of the WO and the "total" costs of the task together -- via the WOTOTAL object and the WORKORDER.WOTOTAL relationship.

Comment: The description of the WORKORDER.WOTOTAL relationship says, *"Relationship to the nonpersistent set that calculates work order totals for a work order **and its tasks.**"*